# How to send message from background to content script that inside in offscreen and iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have the next chain: `background` > `offscreen` > `iframe` > `inner content script`. For this target in manifest set `all_frames` to `true`. How to send message from `background` to `inner content script`?

The `chrome.tabs.queue` don't return such tab id in order to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. Other `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` only for `offscreen`.

Comment: You need to reverse the direction of communication and let the content script connect via chrome.runtime.sendMessage or chrome.runtime.connect. Note that this is a safe secure method, unlike using iframeWindow.postMessage which can be intercepted by the site.